# Is there are other locations for Spring XML schemas

Tags: spring, xsd, location

I have Spring applicationContext file that is referring to several XML schemas. These schemas used to locate at http://www.springframework.org/schema. I still can access those locations via web browser, however via application I can't access them while on the company network.
When I do it on my home computer everything works fine.
I did find out via **wget** utility, that while trying to access those schemas, that it redirects to the *spring.io* site. Looks like our company network security blocks those redirects.
I did try to find those XML schemas on spring.io site, but got 404 code.

If someone knows how to access these XML schemas without redirects, I would appreciate a tip.

Comment: All of the schema are still available in the site you pointed out. Example : [security](https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd), [beans](https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd) or [oxm](https://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd)

Comment: They are in the jars and spring will automatically get them from the jar it doesn't go to the internet for that.

Comment: Maybe change protocol to https ?

Comment: I tried to change protocol to https and it does not help.

Comment: XML files are in the JAR, but not XSD files. At least I didn't find them there.